# SwiftUI: How can I access an ObservedObject within a Pageable?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, viewmodel

I am trying to access a Textfield from a child view which lives within a Pageable in the MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {
      var pages = [
        UIHostingController(rootView: FirstView(viewModel: viewModel)), // 1. error (without lazy var pages)
        UIHostingController(rootView: SecondaryView()), 
      ] 

     @StateObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
     @State var pageIndex = 0
     var body: some View{
         HStack{
              Pageable(pageIndex: $pageIndex, viewControllers: pages) // 2. error (with lazy var pages)
         }
     }
}  
struct FirstView: View {
        @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
        var body: some View{
             NameTextfield(text: $viewModel.name, placeholder: Text("Name…"))
        }
}
```

1. At first, the build fails because it can't use the instance member viewModel *as the property initializers run before 'self' is available.*
2. If I use lazy var pages it accepts the viewModel in the rootView but throws an error at viewControllers: pages, that it *cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable*

Is there a way to pass the viewModel to the rootView in this scenario, so that I can access the Textfield from the views in the MainView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `init`

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        NameTextfield(text: $viewModel.name, placeholder: Text("Name…"))
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    @State var pageIndex = 0
    
    private var pages: [UIViewController] = []
    
    init() { //<---Here
        pages = [UIHostingController(rootView: FirstView(viewModel: viewModel)), UIHostingController(rootView: SecondaryView())]
    }

    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Pageable(pageIndex: $pageIndex, viewControllers: pages)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I `print("\(viewModel.name)")` in the MainView, I get nothing/ nil. In the `init()` on the `FirstView(...)`, I get the purple warning: `"Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time."`

Comment: Update: It works once I change the `StateObject` to an `ObservedObject` in the MainView